# Can not push_back into a static member which type is array of std::vector<int>

Tags: c++, stl, static-members

I have the following setup:

a class with a **static member** which is like:
`static std::vector<int> m_Some[3];`

**The problem is**, I cant `m_Some[0].push_back(x)` with it.
It triggers an error in `<vector>`'s `insert()` and then in `operator-`.
But somehow the callstack is wrong for further actions so I cant see what's real happening.

**If I do** `m_Some[0].reserve(1);` **before** `push_back`, 
then I can make 1 `push_back`, but failed in the second `push_back`.

I have totally no idea why it can't just `push_back` and has to `reserve` first...
And I event cant `push_back` more than the size I `reserve`.

I tried a **local variable** with same type of array, and it performs correctly with `push_back`.

I'm compiling using VS2008.

Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Comment: [This works fine](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f2748874e43d6586793469d3ed087a4d). You need to describe your problem with more detail. Perhaps post a small program that exhibits this error?

Comment: Ideally, you should post a self-contained, compilable piece of code which exposes the problem. Often, just doing this exercise leads you to where the bug is.

Comment: Are you calling push_back from a constructor of another static? In which case your vectors might not be constructed yet? Probably not, but there isn't much to go on in the question.

Comment: Maybe he's experiencing a static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: my codes are similar to @R.MartinhoFernandes's post, I'm trying to edit for code snippets.

Comment: @J99, yes I am calling it within a constructor of a global variable...! (declared in an .cpp) (but not static). I think that's the problem, I'll try to modify the code and see the result!

Comment: @J99 and akappa: Exactly the problem is, the vector initialzation is after my calling in the constructor...I'll try to solve that problem then. Thanks!! (How to mark the comment as the answer?!)

Comment: @MarsonMao You cannot. Just answer your own question and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you **calling push_back from a constructor of another static**? In which case your vectors might not be constructed yet? Probably not, but there isn't much to go on in the question. – **J99** 44 mins ago

Maybe he's experiencing a **static initialization order fiasco**. – **akappa** 43 mins ago

@J99, yes **I am calling it within a constructor of a global variable**...! (declared in an .cpp) (but not static). I think that's the problem, I'll try to modify the code and see the result! – Marson Mao 33 mins ago

@J99 and akappa: Exactly the problem is, **the vector initialzation is after my calling in the constructor**...I'll try to solve that problem then. Thanks!! (How to mark the comment as the answer?!) – Marson Mao 27 mins ago

@MarsonMao You cannot. Just answer your own question and mark it as accepted – akappa 8 mins ago

Above are the answers!
Thanks for the help :)